# Simple database management tool

Tags: database, sql

I have  a very simple website complemented by a database (MySQL) with a couple of tables which are used in the website to render some pages. For ease of talk, this website simply lists a set of products.

Providing a CMS is outside of the scope of this project. What I do need however is a very simple database management system where the user, without much computer experience can manipulate the products (insert, delete and update). Note that we also support photos (each product has a thumbnail and 0 or more photos shown in a slideshow).

So there is no need to have a CMS where the user can change the HTML parts, just the products themselves (price, title, description, photo....).

Authentication and authorization is a nice to have but not required.

Does anyone know if such a simple product exists?

Hosting should be compatible with an expected LAMP configuration. Furthermore, free of charge and opensource is preferred.

Thanks!

Comment: Price? PHP/Ruby/...? Please [edit] your question

Comment: Most hosters have [phpMyAdmin](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/) pre-installed on the server. You might wish to check whether that's already sufficient for your needs.

Comment: "There is no need to ..", BUT **could** the user change *everything* in the database, or do you want to configure your solution to only allow him access to certain tables, even columns?

Comment: If you use PHP & CodeIgniter than you really can't beat http://www.grocerycrud.com/ - but I can't post that as an answer, because your question has so little detail.